# import data from a csv file into mongoDB collection with meteor

Tags: excel, mongodb, meteor

i would like to get data from a csv file into a mongoDB collection using Meteor js and i would be grateful for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [papa-parse](https://atmospherejs.com/harrison/papa-parse) and read csv file using Node file system like this:

```
var fs = Npm.require('fs');
// Assume that the csv file is in yourApp/public/data folder
var data = fs.readFileSync(process.env.PWD + '/public/data/yourCSV.csv', 'utf8');
var usersData = Papa.parse(data, {header: true});
```

The userData will in the JSON format, you can store it in the MongoDb as you want.

Answer (score 0):

[csv-parse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parse) is used to parse csv files. Loading the MongoDB collection can be done via the [upsert method](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-upsert) of Meteor collection.